# Gulp webserver task and watch task not works together

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Here I have a watch task that will create my `build` directory according to my `src`. My `build` directory will contain two main sub directories named `debug` and `release`. Watch task will look inside of my src directory(my working directory) and will transfer appropriate format of files inside the src into both `release` and `debug` directories. Now I also have a webserver task using `gulp-webserver`(live reloading) package in order to watching my `index.html` file inside my debug directory. My problem is that each task works independently, but I don't know how run them simultaneously. Here is what I've tried but it didn't work(just one of them will be start). Let me know if further information is needed.

```
// watch
gulp.task('watch',()=>{
    gulp.watch(pathJS,gulp.series('js','js-min'));
    gulp.watch(pathSCSS,gulp.series('sass','sass-min'));
    gulp.watch(['src/**/*.*','!'+pathJS,'!'+pathSCSS],gulp.series('cp','cp-min'));
});
// webserver
gulp.task('webserver',()=>{
    gulp.src(buildOptions.debugPath)
        .pipe(webServer({
            fallback: 'index.html',
            port:'4000',
            livereload:true,
            open:true
        }))
});
.
.
.
var default_tasks = ['build', 'webserver', 'watch'];
gulp.task('default',gulp.series('clean',...default_tasks));
```

**EDIT:**
Here is my full `gulpfile.js`:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const del = require('del');
const webServer = require('gulp-webserver');
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const build_tasks=['js','js-min','sass','sass-min','cp','cp-min'];
const buildOptions={
    releasePath:'build/release/',
    debugPath:'build/debug/',
};
const pathJS = 'src/js/**/*.js'
const pathSCSS = 'src/style/**/*.scss'
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// JavaScript Task
gulp.task('js',()=>{
    return gulp.src([pathJS])
            .pipe(gulp.dest(buildOptions.debugPath+'/js/'));
});
gulp.task('js-min',()=>{
    return gulp.src([pathJS])
            .pipe(uglify().on('error',uglify=>console.error(uglify.message)))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(buildOptions.releasePath+'/js/'));
})
// sass Task
gulp.task('sass',()=>{
    return gulp.src([pathSCSS])
            .pipe(sass().on('error',sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(buildOptions.debugPath+'/style/'));
});
gulp.task('sass-min',()=>{
    return gulp.src([pathSCSS])
            .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error',sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(buildOptions.releasePath+'/style/'))

})
// copy files
gulp.task('cp',()=>{
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.*','!'+pathJS,'!'+pathSCSS])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildOptions.debugPath));
});
gulp.task('cp-min',()=>{
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.*','!'+pathJS,'!'+pathSCSS])
            .pipe(gulp.dest(buildOptions.releasePath));
});
// watch
gulp.task('watch',()=>{
    gulp.watch(pathJS,gulp.series('js','js-min'));
    gulp.watch(pathSCSS,gulp.series('sass','sass-min'));
    gulp.watch(['src/**/*.*','!'+pathJS,'!'+pathSCSS],gulp.series('cp','cp-min'));
});
// webserver
gulp.task('webserver',()=>{
    gulp.src(buildOptions.debugPath)
        .pipe(webServer({
            fallback: 'index.html',
            port:'4000',
            livereload:true,
            open:true
        }))
});
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('clean',function(){return del(['build']);});
gulp.task('build',gulp.parallel(...build_tasks));
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function build(){
    var default_tasks = ['build', 'webserver', 'watch'];
    //var default_tasks = ['build', 'watch'];
    gulp.task('default',gulp.series('clean',...default_tasks));
}
build();
```

Comment: You should include your clean and build tasks.  Do you have return statements in them?  To signal completion.

Comment: @Mark, Tanks for your response. Please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem by using `gulp.parallel` for both `webserver` and `watch` tasks :

```
// watch
gulp.task('watch',()=>{
    gulp.watch(pathJS,gulp.series('js','js-min'));
    gulp.watch(pathSCSS,gulp.series('sass','sass-min'));
    gulp.watch(['src/**/*.*','!'+pathJS,'!'+pathSCSS],gulp.series('cp','cp-min'));
});
// webserver
gulp.task('webserver',()=>{
    gulp.src(buildOptions.debugPath)
        .pipe(webServer({
            fallback: 'index.html',
            port:'4000',
            livereload:true,
            open:true
        }))
});
.
.
.
gulp.task('default',gulp.series('clean','build',gulp.parallel('webserver', 'watch')));//Here is my change!
```